# MakeFeatureLayer_management where_clause input by the user

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool, where-clause

I want to convert a script into a toolbox and one of the parameters is selecting cities with a population > than 500000 hab. I'm using the function MakeFeatureLayer_management.

How can I do to introduce the value of the {where_clause} ('"POP_MAX" > 500000') using arcpy.GetParameterAsText?

```
import arcpy    
from arcpy import env    
env.overwriteOutput = True

wsp = env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)    
wsp_result = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

try:    
  arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management ("cities" + "layer_cities",'"POP_MAX" > 500000')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should create a new parameter of the `SQL Expression` data type and then set the `Obtained from` option to point to the feature class parameter. This will let user see all the attributes of the feature class he/she has chosen (much like Select By Attribute dialog window).

[image]

If you don't want to expose the feature classes's attributes, then just create a `String` parameter that will contain the SQL query (user will enter the query `POP_MAX" > 500000` and this implies that they know the names of the fields) or a `Long` parameter (integer) to specify the value only and then you can use the value in the query in your code:

```
userThreshold = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
query = """ "POP_MAX" > {0} """.format(userThreshold)
```

If you don't know which data source your users will be working with, it might be good to use the [AddFieldDelimiters](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//03q300000091000000) function which will let you use correct syntax for specifying the field name.

```
sql_exp = """{0} = '{1}'""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters('c:/data', field_name),state_value)
```